# Rails layout error in Chrome but Firefox show's fine

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, firefox, layout

I'm working in a site where the footer show's well in firefox but chrome shows error's. By errors, I mean, just look the images below:

**Firefox** one.

[image]

And this is the **chrome** one:

[image]

This is my **footer partial: **

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom">

<div class="row-fluid">

    <div class="span4" id="foo_left">
        <ul>
            <li><%= link_to "About Us" , '/about' %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Contact" , '/contact' %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "How it Works" , '/howitworks' %></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="span4" id="company"><p>Copyright 2013 Rawdi. All rights reserved.</p></div>

    <div class="span4" id="foo_right">
        <ul>
            <li><%= link_to "Privacy" , '/privacy' %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Terms & Policies" , '/tnc' %></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

This is the **css for that (SASS):**

```
#footer {
padding-top: 10px;
margin-top:15px;
.row-fluid {
    padding-top:10px;
    background-color: #060606;
    #foo_left {
        float:left;
        ul {
            list-style: none;
            li {
                display: inline;
                border-right: 1px solid grey;
                a {
                    margin: 5px 10px 5px 5px;
                }
                    a:hover {
                    text-decoration: none;
                    margin: 5px 10px 5px 5px;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    #foo_right {
        float:right;
        ul {
            float:right;
            list-style: none;
            margin-right: 10px;
            li {
                display: inline;
                border-right: 1px solid grey;
                a {
                    margin: 5px 10px 5px 5px;
                }
                    a:hover {
                    text-decoration: none;
                    margin: 5px 10px 5px 5px;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    #company {
        float:center;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
}
}
```

And this is the **application.html.erb** for more info:

```
<body>

<div id="header" class="container"><%= render 'layouts/header' %><%= render 'layouts/dropdown' unless @disable_dropdown %></div>
<div class="container" id="body">
<%= yield %>

</div>

<div id="footer" class="container-fluid"><%= render 'layouts/footer' %></div>
```

Why is this happening? why chorme and firefox are showing different layouts? Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing `float: center`.

Also you don't need float when you have assigned `span4` to each div.

Comment: @Mrudul_T, Firefox works fine doesn't mean it is correct. Every browser has slight difference. Stick to good practice and you'll be fine at all.